# Get Woocommerce order id by a billing field

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

May I know that if there a way to get WooCommerce order ID by a value from billing detail? My main goal here is getting order status (order tracking) but I have done it with order ID. Which mean if customer provides order ID the website will show his/her order status. But somehow my client wanted to make it available to check with another unique value which his clients have to submit in billing detail.

I have been thinking how to get order status directly or get order ID and then status if I have that unique value billing detail. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. But if it unique, of course.

```
global $wpdb;
$order_id=$wpdb->get_var("select post_id from $wpdb->postmeta where meta_key='_billing_address_1' and meta_value='".esc_sql($billing_address_here))."'";

//or

global $wpdb;
$order_id=$wpdb->get_var("select post_id from $wpdb->postmeta where meta_key='_billing_phone' and meta_value='".esc_sql($billing_phone_here)."'");
```

Comment: I am sorry but that only works for post_id. What I want is order_id and I found that Woocommerce store billing information in wp_usermeta table. So I modified your code but I get empty value. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Hi Elvin,
Thank you! I got it now. I think there is syntax error in your code which produce database error but based on your concept, I read more about wpdb and my issue was solved with following code.

`$order_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "
  SELECT post_id 
  FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
  WHERE meta_key = '_billing_company'
  AND meta_value = '%s'
 ", $billing_company ) );`

Please change your code so that I could select your answer as correct.

Comment: Hi. Edited. There was missing quote for meta value.